# Why is this returning "org.apache.derby.client.net.NetResultSet42@1b5f7aa"

Tags: java, derby

i am trying to display my database into a text area in java. The code below works however it is showing "org.apache.derby.client.net.NetResultSet42@1b5f7aa" instead of the data. Any Ideas why? and how i can correct this

**My Code**

```
public static String listAll() {
    String output = listHeader();
    try {
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from STUDENT.MESSAGES");
        while (res.next()) { // there is a result
            //output += formatListEntry(res);
            output += res;
            output +=System.lineSeparator();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`ResultSet` doesn't implement `toString` method, so what you're seeing is the default implementation defined in `Object#toString`.

You should, instead, obtain the data from the `ResultSet` using `ResultSet#getXyz` method:

```
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from STUDENT.MESSAGES");
while (res.next()) { // there is a result
    //output += formatListEntry(res);
    output += res.getString("column1");
    output += " ";
    output += res.getString("column2");
    output +=System.lineSeparator();
}
```

Some recommendations:

- In your queries, retrieve the relevant columns, don't use `"*"`. Use this for **testing purposes only**.
- When reading data from `ResultSet`, it's better to use the names of the columns rather than the expected index. This is in case somebody else alters the table and adds a column in the middle of them, and also it helps readability and debugability of the code.
- If you have to read several rows from the database, it's better to return a `List<YourObject>` rather than a giant String.

Comment: or you can use res.getString(1) for first column and so on perhaps with a for loop

Comment: @JackTools.Net read the recommendations. It's better to use `"columnName"` rather than indexes due to changes in the query, specially when somebody adds a column in the middle of it.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @JackTools.Net it depends if you want to have a good or very bad design.

Answer (score 0):

This is why: `output += res;`

res is a `org.apache.derby.client.net.NetResultSet` and that class doesn't override `toString()`.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help. Now it works however the data displayed is totally incorrect? it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

`res.toString()` will return `org.apache.derby.client.net.NetResultSet42@1b5f7aa`

you have to Change:

```
output += res;
```

to

```
output = res.getString(0);
```

to see the first value and add all other in same style.